# Concatenate first name and last name initial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Chakra UI Avatar component. Only the first name initial is shown when I try to do this: Payload is the data I get from my API through Redux

```js
<Avatar name={ user && user.payload?.firstName.charAt(0) + "" + user.payload?.lastName.charAt(0) } />
```

Comment: what's payload?

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: payload is data I'm getting from API through redux toolkit @Rick

Comment: so much wrong with this post. first of all adding text to a name field is not going to display anything to the screen.

Comment: Only the first name initial appears @luk2302

Comment: + "" + does the same thing as +

Comment: It's not clear what the actual **issue** is. Tangential: this is not a helpful snippet.

Comment: It's not a name field. It's props of Avatar component from Chakra UI @Rick

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering suggests a syntax error in your code. In React, JSX expressions should be enclosed in curly braces {}. Additionally, you need to provide a string as the name prop for the Avatar component. You can modify your code as follows:

```
<Avatar name={user && `${user.payload?.firstName.charAt(0)} ${user.payload?.lastName.charAt(0)}`} />
```

Comment: The JSX expression **is** wrapped in curly braces. The difference is that the concatenation is handled by a single interpolated expression, functionally equivalent to wrapping the concatenation in parens.